# Why doesn't $f'$ have to be continuous at $c$ in this situation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

My friend asks me about this problem.

> $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, for $c\in (a,b)$, exists a sequence $x_n\to c$ and $\lim f'(x_n)=f'(c)$, how to show that $f'$ doesn't have to be continuous at $c$?

I know 'there exists' such a sequence does not guarantee that it's true for any sequence converging to $c$, but I can't think of a counterexample.  Can anybody prove it or find a counterexample? This problem is kinda interesting and I want to know the answer:) Thanks!!!

Comment: I think something like $f(x)=x^\alpha \sin({1\over x^\beta})$ would work for appropriate $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: What is $f'$? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I assumed that $F$ and $f$ were not supposed to be different functions. If not, you should elaborate on their relationship.

Comment: @lebesgue: f' is the derivative of f

Comment: Trivial counterexample : take $f$ such that $f'$ is not continuous at $0$ and take $x_n=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a "hand waving" proof that an example exists:

Take $$f(x)=\cases{x^2\sin (\textstyle{1\over x}), &x\ne 0\cr 0, &x=0}$$

The graph of this function is

[image]

$f$ is differentiable for all $x\ne0$. In fact,
for $x\ne0$:
$$
f'(x) = 2x\sin (\textstyle{1\over x})-  \cos(\textstyle{1\over x}).
$$

One can show $f'(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Indeed, for $x\ne0$:
$$
\eqalign{
{f(x)-f(0)\over x-0} = x\sin(\textstyle{1\over x})\ \buildrel{x\rightarrow 0}\over \longrightarrow\ 0.
}
$$

Also, one can find a sequence $x_n\searrow 0$ for which $f'(x_n)=0$ for each $n$ (look at the horizontal tangents of the graph). But $f'$ is not continuous at zero since it takes values of both 0 and $a$ in every neighborhood of $0$ for some $a>0$ (to see this, look at the formula for $f'(x)$ above and consider:   $2x\sin(\textstyle{1\over x})$  becomes small for small $x$ and  $-\cos(\textstyle{1\over x})$  takes the value 1 at some point of every nhood of $0$).